# website links with string auto attached

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I made a new website for someone but when i tried to launch it live i had problems with links. The old version of the site had language extension.

Now every link with the domain:

```
sites.com get extension ( ex: www.site.com/**es**/; wwww.site.com/**en**/,www.site.com/**es**/contact)
```

Even thow i made dynamic links i have problems accessing the `wordpress`admin and also i have problems with referencing the homepage from other pages (only way i was able to to refence the homepage was by making something like site.com#).

After every change in `wordpress` admin the links are adjusted with language extension/string.

Comment: So your question is...? How do you link to the homepage? Or how do you access the admin?

Comment: my question is how i can i delete that "reference" extension or where i can search for a solution to eliminate the problem.
I delete all the files from htdocs and i don't know from where it comes that script that attached the string to my links.
I can acces the wpadmin after i delete the reference manualy but every move/change on wpadmin redirects to the page with extension sites.com/es/wp-admin/post... and i have to delete the string and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all language extensions you could run a query in the form:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'site.com/es/', 'site.com/') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%site.com/es/%'
```

On your database for each language extension. This will remove all references in post content. You'll also want to check your `wp_options` table, replacing finds in the `option_value` field.

Finally run a check on the `wp_postmeta` table - many items will be serialised values and so can't be changed with a simple find/replace like above. Instead you should run a find, then figure out how to change any found values via the Wordpress admin panel.

As always **back up your database before playing around**.

Comment: By making changes to the database will not solve the real problem. Every time someone will edit something in wp admin will bring the problem back.

Comment: How so? If the options table is fixed WP won't use the old links in future, and if the content table is fixed all existing links will be fixed.

Comment: I will try what you told me to see if it works to show me the wp-admin in the right way.
The problem is not with old links. I made a new website from scratch. The problem is that every "new link" gets extension.The old website was made without database.
I want to find out the root of the problem.